# Using Twisted static web server for sharing python resource files

Tags: python, twisted

can anyone advice the best way to share Python package resource files with Twisted web server?

Package built using setuptools.

```
from pkg_resources import resource_listdir

from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.static import File
from twisted.internet import reactor

resource = File('/blah') # !! Wanna ask File use resource_listdir
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8888, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `listNames` on `File` to control directory listings.

For example,

```
packageName = "..."

class PkgResourcesFile(File):
    def listNames(self):
        return resource_listdir(packageName, self.path)

resource = PkgResourcesFile(...)
```